# capture and respond to Postgres fatal error in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, security, exception, whitelist

As one of the security measures of my Rails app, my Postgres instance is configured to issue a FATAL error and disallow an SQL query from running if the SQL isn't in the "whitelist". This is done by using the [sql_firewall](http://pgsnaga.blogspot.jp/2015/08/postgresql-sql-firewall.html) extension for postgres.

When one of these FATAL errors is triggered, I want to code the Rails app to respond in a certain way.

Without putting `begin` `catch` `end` individually around all my ActiveRecord `find` `where` `save` calls, is there a callback that's triggered after *any* query to the database (no mater whether it was a `SELECT` `INSERT` `UPDATE` or `DELETE`) where I can see whether this specific type of FATAL error has occurred and I can then execute the particular code I wish?

**Background**

For instance, a rails app has a known set of queries it will ever run. If I add those to a whitelist in PostgreSQL then it'll block any other queries by issuing a fatal error.

This is a extra security defence and protects from a flaw in my application layer being leveraged to allow a malicious user finding a way to `SELECT * FROM Users`.

Comment: See if there's an interceptor lower in the ActiveRecord execution path